# How to setState of an object without overwrite other items in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, rxjs, react-hooks

i have a state in react which is an object from an external class

Class Example:

```
export class Customers{ 
    tm_name?: string | null;
    tm_last_name?: string | null;
    tm_gender?: string | null;
}
```

i imported the file and then I created and state from that class

State Example:

```
this.state = { 
    customerObj: new Customers()
};
```

after that if I debugg my class and look at the customerObj state it has all of 3 properties (empty but it has my 3 class properties)

the problem is, when im trying to set only ONE value of customerObj like tm_gender  using setState  it erases all others  properties like tm_name and tm_gender

Example of setState:

```
this.setState({
            customerObj : { 
                tm_last_name: e.value }});  
    }
```

is there a way to use setState for only some of the state/object(customerObj) properties and and keep the other properties intact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
this.setState({
  customerObj : { 
    ...this.state.customerObj,
    tm_last_name: e.value 
  }
});
```

...Operator allows you to keep existing properties of old `customerObj`, and `tm_last_name: e.value` will override only `tm_last_name`